# Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Activity in Android App Development from the main

Tags: android, menu

Why am I getting the error from line 21 "onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)"

package com.example.movieplayer;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    private boolean **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu**) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The onCreateOptions menu is specified in the base class.  The method has a visibility of public.  Since you are overriding that method you can't change that to private.

so:

```
@Override
public boolean **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu**) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```